# Вывод одинаковых значений из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно составить программу, которая вынесет одинаковые значения из данного списка.
На вход программе сначала подаётся значение n ≤ 100. В следующей строке расположены n элементов массива — целые числа, по модулю не превосходящие 30000. Числа нужно выводить согласно их первому появлению в списке
Ввод:
8
4 3 5 2 5 1 3 5
Вывод:
3 5
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Копия вопроса -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Comment: Порядок вывода имеет значение?

Comment: Было бы всё так просто. Мне требуется получить только повторяющиеся элементы, без их количества в списке.

Comment: Вопрос обновил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
list_ = [8, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 5]
print(list(set(i for i in list_ if list_.count(i) > 1)))
# [3, 5]
```

Если важен порядок из изначального списка то:

```py
print(sorted(list(set(i for i in list_ if list_.count(i) > 1)), key=list_.index))
```

> Если нужны пояснения, спрашивайте, дополню ответ.

Comment: А зачем превращать в сет потом, если можно сразу по сету итероваться?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov можно, согласен.

Comment: И вместо лямбды можно сразу `key=list_.index`

Comment: @PavelDurmanov, и это в точку, но это уже больше привычка